# How to animate changing slides? slow-quick-slow motion

Tags: jquery, animation, slick.js

I was asked to do animation on a [Slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) (basic JSfiddle for example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/erwinsmit/wsrvtwL4/)) which would start slowly (like a car getting into motion), than move quickly and stop slowly. But I have no idea how to achieve this. Could anybody point me a right direction?

```
<section class="slider">
    <div>Hover me and I'll pause</div>
    <div>Unhover and I'll resume</div>
    <div>But not if you've paused me</div>
    <div>I wont restart when changing slides</div>
    <div>I will also pause when focussed</div>
    <div>Huzzah.</div>
</section>

<script>
$(".slider").slick({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    pauseOnFocus: true,
    dots: true,
});
</script>
```

Thanks a lot, your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Look into the easing functions of Slick.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rick Calder and his hint, I have found this topic: [Slick Carousel Easing Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600544/slick-carousel-easing-examples)

And using this https://easings.net/ I have chosen https://easings.net/#easeInOutCubic animation which can be applied on slick as:

```
cssEasing: 'cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1)',
```

So simple! Thanks a lot!