# Make a left to right slider background transition with zoom out effect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've been trying to replicate this cool background image slider that I saw in this website.

URL : https://soto.shinfuji.co.jp/

I tried using slick slider that I knew but still can't figure out that smooth left to right transition and also the zoom out effects. Is there any other JS library I can use to make this slider ?

The slide that I made :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('.demo').slick({
    arrows: 1,
    dots: 1,
    cssEase: "ease-out",
    autoplay: true
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.slick-slide {
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="slider demo">
    <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1674240568812-d7481f3699a7?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1528&q=80" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1573996987033-47fd3a4ca35e?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80" alt=""></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean the forest of the background?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify which part of the site.
Yeah it's the forest background on the top page of the site that transition to mountain background etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an informative older post about same subject (other than your last 'zoom' question).
[older stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600544/slick-carousel-easing-examples)

Here's a Slick Slider tutorial on all the basic setup options.
[codepen tutorial](https://codepen.io/crux1/pen/eYjMYRb)

```
<script>
$('.cssEase').slick({
    arrows:true,
    infinite:true,
    slidesToShow:3,
    slidesToScroll:3,
    autoplay:false,
    autoplaySpeed:500,
    dots:true,
    useTransform: true,
    cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045)'
});
</script>
```

Either web link should help solve certain basic Slick Slider factors for sliding left or right.
As for the zoom in/out factor....

Comment: Hey ! @granite
Sorry for the late reply, I tried using the slick slide option that you've provided but it doesn't do what I imagine. So I've been experimenting with GSAP right now. I'll gonna post another question when I hit another problem. Thanks for the advice.